# Kafka disk access while reading and writing

Tags: apache-kafka, disk-io

According to Kafka doc https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#persistence, Kafka utilities squential read/write performace of spnning disks and hence have high throughput. But how can this high throughput be maintained when node1 with disk1 is sequentially writing in paritition but a list of consumers also reading from that parition and disk1 have to move disk head to read partition.

Shouldnt this parallel reads and write in a spinning disk get into way of achieving high throughput?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka uses `sendfile` system calls, pagecache, and zero-copy transfer for consumers, as explained in the [efficiency](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#maximizingefficiency) section of the docs.

Also, `logs.dir` config can use multiple volumes (i.e. multiple physically mounted disks). It is true that having one disk is expected to be slower than many, in parallel.

Comment: Be it one disk or many, every disk has to do parallel read and write for any x partition. How are overall operations are sequential?

Comment: Disks spin hundreds of times per second. For example, 5400/7200 RPM... And deliver between 100/120 MB/s transfer rates, on average. I'm not sure I understand the concern. Kafka records have a default max message size of 1MB, so you could send up to 120 large records _per second_ to max out _one disk_, per topic partition . So, in your day to day operations of browsing the web, streaming data, reading email, etc, some of that is also writing to disk. And no one operation is blocking others. Even before SSD, none of that was considerably slow.

Comment: Reminder that Kafka shouldn't be used for file transfers. I've rarely seen Kafka records be larger than a few hundred kB, especially after serialized as compact binary encoding events (not plaintext) and compressed

Comment: concern is simple, that disks provides 100 MBps when used sequentially but parallel read/write can make it substantial less. So, kafka has to use a buffer after it received msgs before persisiting it and if it uses buffer that how can kafka avoid OS paging out that chunk?

Comment: I don't know the storage internals of Kafka. Perhaps you can ask Kafka developer mailing list  for more speciifics